# Python sending e-mail with SMTP without authentication

Tags: python, email

I'm making a script that notifies people about some pending tickets in JIRA. These notifications are sent by e-mail, I already got the notification to trigger, but I'm having problems sending the emails.

I can send them using gmail but when I tried to do it with my official account (the one that the company gave me) I am not able to send them. IT guys already provided me the 'localhost' because they use SMTP relays and the port, but they keep telling me that I should start SMTP without authentication, I'm not very sure of how to do this.

The example I found on internet was this:

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'Axel.Sa@mydomain.com'
toaddrs = ['Axel.Sa@mydomain.com']
msg = '''
    From: {fromaddr}
    To: {toaddr}
    Subject: testin'
    This is a test
    .
'''

msg = msg.format(fromaddr=fromaddr, toaddr=toaddrs[0])
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost:25')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo("mydomain.com")
server.mail(fromaddr)
server.rcpt(toaddrs[0])
server.data(msg)
server.quit()
```

But I keep getting this error, If someone can tell me the proper way of sending emails by SMTP without authentication I will be very grateful.

[image: Error by python console]

Comment: did you found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this stack:
[How to send an email without login to server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672983/how-to-send-an-email-without-login-to-server-in-python)

---

change your `smtplib.SMTP('localhost:25')` to `smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 25)`