# How to send an email without login to server in Python

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I want to send an email without login to server in Python. I am using Python 3.6.
I tried some code but received an error. Here is my Code :

```
import smtplib                          

smtpServer='smtp.yourdomain.com'      
fromAddr='from@Address.com'         
toAddr='to@Address.com'     
text= "This is a test of sending email from within Python."
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer)
server.set_debuglevel(1)         
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text) 
server.quit()
```

I expect the mail should be sent without asking user id and password but getting an error :

> "smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.1 Client was not authenticated', 'from@Address.com')"

Comment: Most mail servers are configured to refuse to do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below worked for me.
First, I opened/enabled Port 25 through Network Team and used it in the program.

```
import smtplib                          
smtpServer='smtp.yourdomain.com'      
fromAddr='from@Address.com'         
toAddr='to@Address.com'     
text= "This is a test of sending email from within Python."
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer,25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text) 
server.quit()
```

Comment: what is "s" in "s.ehlo()"?

Comment: it's not coming with subject and body.

Comment: I am getting the error `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time` while attempting to follow this step. Could someone please suggest.

Answer (score 13):

I am using like this. It's work to me in my private SMTP server.

```
import smtplib

host = "server.smtp.com"
server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
FROM = "testpython@test.com"
TO = "bla@test.com"
MSG = "Subject: Test email python\n\nBody of your message!"
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MSG)

server.quit()
print ("Email Send")
```

Comment: this is more accurate I must say. this at least sends subject and body

Answer (score 8):

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook=win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To='To address'
mail.Subject='Message subject'
mail.Body='Message body'
mail.HTMLBody='<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
attachment="Path to the attachment"
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions !!
next time onwards i will look into it.

Comment: This assumes that (a) the user is on Windows and (b) the user uses Outlook. It also uses a massive, buggy, client-side program when a simple SMTP request will do. It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: How would you do it without log in to server with smtp?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to have a SMTP server to send an email. When you don't have one, usually outlook's server is used. But outlook only accepts authenticated users, so if you don't want to login into the server, you have to pick a server that doesn't need authentication.

A second approach is to setup an internal SMTP server. After you setup the internal SMTP server, you can use the "localhost" as the server to send the email. Like this:

```
import smtplib
receiver = 'someonesEmail@hisDomain.com'
sender = 'yourEmail@yourDomain.com'
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')

subject = 'test'
body = 'testing plain text message'
msg = 'subject: ' + subject + ' \n\n' + body

smtp.sendmail('sender', receiver, msg)
```